# How to stop refreshing page on event

Tags: refresh, webrtc

I'm thinking about script which refreshes browsers (chrome) page every few seconds (we can find many add-on on internet which do just that) but the script also stops refreshing page when browser senses incoming call (via WebRTC) and box is displayed in browsers corner (box to answer call). How to handle such event and stop refreshing page then?
Here is simple `javascript` code to refresh every ten minutes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",600000);
  function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",1200000);
  }
</script>
```

I'm thinking about workaround.
How can i do that if i click specific button on page to refresh after 20 minutes (function resetTimeout) (let's say calls wont be longer) and after 20 minutes to refresh again every 10 minutes? 
How to incorporate this script to browser for particular webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i installed chrome injector and for particular page I need to write simple script like this:

```
  var timeout = setTimeout("location.reload(true);",10000);
  function resetTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(10000000);
  }
   function resetTimeout2() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(10000);
  }

$('.button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.pull-left.call').click(resetTimeout());
$('.button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger.pull-left.disabled.hangup').click(resetTimeout2());
```

Refresh page every 6000000ms. If pressed answer then refresh every 10000000ms. If pressed hangup refresh again every 6000000ms. I just need help with syntax with javascript.
when i pressed left.call button resetTimout() do not work, it still refreshes page immediately.

button.animated.fadeIn.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary.pull-left.call and the other one is Button Class element